# The setText in actionListener not calling getter or setters from other classes

Tags: java, actionlistener, settext

The code below is an `ActionListener` in which I implemented a `setText` method to call a method to add a song. I know that `setText` only works with String type but with a little trick (adding "") you should be able to make it work. But it doesn't. Any ideas? Is there an alternative to call a setter from an `ActionListener`?

```
private class AddListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        displayOutput.setText.(""+Object.addSong(object2););

    }
}
```

Comment: error message : setText cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: `(""+Object.addSong(object2);)`have semicolon. try to remove that and add `toString()`

Comment: You're going to run into problems once you fix this error. Class `Object` has no method `addSong()`. Perhaps you meant `object2.addSong()`, where `object2` is of some type which implements `addSong()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're getting:

> setText cannot be resolved or is not a field

is because you have a `.` after `setText`, which is supposed to be a method call.  You'll also need to remove the extra `;` after `(object2)`.

Those errors are going to mask the one you get from calling `addSong` on `Object`, which doesn't have a static method by that name.

Beyond those syntax errors, you'll need to make sure that the `addSong` method (on whatever object you end up calling it) actually returns a value to concatenate to the empty string.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry this code killed me. I really exausted. Working on this code since more than 12 hours. You programmes know what i mean.